# In C#, what does "Customer cust = new Customer();" do?

Tags: c#

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
```

`Customer` is a class. `cust` is an assigned name. I'm not sure what `Customer()` does...

What does this line do? Why do we need it? Isn't having `Customer` and `Customer()` a bit repetitive?

Comment: Next version of C# this will become Customer cust = new();, which looks a lot nicer if you ask me.

Comment: That is nice; the next logical step from `var cust = new Customer()`

Comment: @jcollum:  Nice, I didn't know that.  Too bad I am still on VS2005 at work :-(

Comment: jcollum, what on earth are you talking about?

Comment: I kind of find that syntax disagreeable actually... but perhaps it's easier to skim over that quickly.

Comment: then again, I find the recent mono argument-dropping-suggestion "Func<T> f => result" syntax disagreeable as well.

Comment: Which version of C# are you talking about, jcollum? That doesn't work in C# 4.0 (the one in 2010 Beta 1).

Comment: Eric Lippert blogged about type inference in `new` as a _possible_ feature in _some future_ version of C# _after_ 4.0. Given that their list of "I wish C# had this" features is probably several miles long by now (judging by MS Connect alone, and that's not the only channel), there is absolutely no certainty that it will get into whatever the next C# version after 4.0 is going to be, either.

Comment: Odd, I wouldn't call it "type inference." The type is explicit in the syntax. But "instantiation inference" doesn't sound as nice.

Comment: And even this syntax was only floated by Eric as their compiler doesn't have proper type inference, and so can't cope with var in fields (which, presumably, is what they'd do if it did).

Comment: @jcollum It finally happened in C# 9!

Comment: wow, 11 years after I made that comment, blast from the past!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It declares a Customer and then initializes it.

```
Customer cust; //declares a new variable of Customer type

cust = new Customer(); //Initializes that variable to a new Customer().
```

new creates the actual object, cust hold's a reference to it.

The empty parentheses indicates that the construction of the Customer object is being passed no parameters, otherwise there would be a comma separated list of parameters within the parenthesis.

Answer (score 49):

It creates a new instance of `Customer()` and assigns a reference to the newly created object to the variable `cust`.

If you want to remove the repetition *and* you're using C# 3.0 or later *and* it's a local variable, you can use:

```
var cust = new Customer();
```

That has *exactly* the same meaning - it's still statically typed, i.e. the variable `cust` is still very definitely of type `Customer`.

Now, it *happened* to be repetitive in this case, but the two `Customer` bits are entirely separate. The first is the type of the variable, the second is used to say which constructor to call. They could have been different types:

```
Customer cust = new ValuedCustomer();
IClient cust = new Customer();
object cust = new Customer();
```

etc. It's only because you created an instance of *exactly* the same type as the type of the variable that the repetition occurred.

Answer (score 5):

Customer() is the constructor method on the Customer class. If you're bothered by the repetition, you can use a implicit variable declaration:

var cust = new Customer();

Comment: I don't know how most feel about this, but I would say that in a strongly typed language, this is the wrong way to go.  Of course, this may just be semantics...

Comment: Sure, but as you say it is purely semantic. var is still strongly typed so there's no difference in how the code functions.

Comment: This is ony of my pet peeves with a lot of code I see online these days - I can understand using "var" if you don't know at compile time what object type you are going to get, but if you know exactly what the type is, why not just use it?  It's far more readable and instantly obvious what type of object the variable represents.

Answer (score 4):

The first Customer defines the datatype of the cust variable. The `new Customer()` part creates an instance of the Customer class and assigns it to the variable.

It is not required however that the datatype be `Customer`. If you have the Customer class inherit a different class (say Person) or an interface (say IPayer), you could define it as

```
Person cust = new Customer();
IPayer cust = new Customer();
```

This is one of the basic principles of [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) in object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 3):

```
Customer cust
```

explicitly declares `cust` to be of type `Customer`.

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
```

initializes it by constructing a new `Customer`.

See also [Implicitly Typed Local Variables (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx).

Remember that the LHS variable does not have to be of identical type to the object that is being constructed on the RHS. For example, if `Customer` is a subclass of `Contact`,

```
Contact cust = new Customer();
```

See [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 2):

Plain and simple:
It creates a new Object of the Class Customer.

Answer (score 2):

It is declaring a `Customer` object called `cust` and assigning it a new instance of the class with no parameters being passed to the object's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something only C# does, Objective C and Java do this as well. You need to define the class you will be using for that variable. Then what you are confused about, that part is what initiates the class and assigns it to the variable.

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Test"];
```

You might want to look into [Typcasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)

Answer (score 1):

If you hate repetitiveness like I do, use var

```
var cust = new Customer();
```

... and cust is now *strongly-and-statically-typed* as an instance of Customer

Answer (score 1):

use

```
var cust = new Customer();
```

to avoid the repetition.  In general the pattern is there so that you

1) declare an instance of Customer called cust
2) initialize it. not that you could have other ways of initializing like

```
Customer cust = CustomerProvider.NextCustomer();
```

Comment: You're declaring a *variable* of type Customer called cust. You can declare that variable and never end up with an instance of Customer at all (it could remain null forever).

Answer (score 0):

this line instantiates your object. basically, this means you have a new instance of the Customer object that is set to its preset defaults.

Answer (score 0):

This is C#'s java-esque style showing.  This is the exact syntax you would use in Java to declare a new object.

In case you're still confused, although there are already great answers, it may make it less confusing if you think of "Customer cust" just as you would "int i".  You're declaring a new variable (cust) of a certain type (Customer).

If you're new to object oriented programming, it just takes some patience.  OO thinking is a bit confusing at first, but once it clicks, you'll get it for life.